# How can i search for numbers in a particular line

Tags: regex

I need help finding the numbers for a specific line.

This is the entire text:

```
Circular No. 00-00-0000-000-C
Guayaquil, June XX, 20xx
Subject: FISCAL INSTRUCTION No. 12345678910
Mister
General Manager
For your knowledge and pertinent purposes, please attach hereto, in
...
```

I have this:

```
(Subject.*\n)
```

Finds the line that says Subject but I am missing the numbers.

Expected result (with only numbers):

```
12345678910
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using ECMAScript flavor
Here is your answer

```
(?<=Subject.*)\d+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hSY6VW/1

I have also test with vscode and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can make use of a capture group, I would phrase your regex as:

```
^Subject: .* No\. (\d+)
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zy9KAA/1).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I want to get only the numbers

Comment: Then the best you might be able to do is: `(?<=\bNo\. )\d+` ... what regex tool are you using here?

Comment: I don't want to search with "No" because it might change to "Nro", "Number", etc. I am using Uipath validator

Comment: Then you need to edit your question with this information.  My answer (and comments) above are as good as I can suggest based on what you have posted already.

Comment: I just edited it